# Re-reading offset after kafka server reboot

Tags: apache-kafka

Setting the autocommit.enable option for the Kafka consumer causes consumed messages to be committed, which means that if a consumer crashes, it will start reading offsets from the last committed position.

But what if we restart kafka server, will the consumer re-read already committed offsets or this option works in such case as well - after server reboot only unread message will be consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked (sort of):

> Does the consumer re-read message before the committed offset?

The answer is no. Once your offset is committed on the server, the consumers won't re-read any message (unless they manually want to).

But you might want to be asking this question to yourself:

> Is it possible for consumers to consume the same message multiple
>   times even if they enable autocommit?

The answer to that is "not without effort". To understand why, read section 4.6 of [Kafka design](https://kafka.apache.org/08/design.html). Kafka doesn't provide exactly-once delivery guarantees on the consumers side. In order to make sure that multiple consumers don't consume the same messages you need to coordinate between your consumer clients.

The other option is to make all your messages [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). That way it doesn't matter if multiple consumers process the same message several times.

Answer (score 1):

The committed offset works across Kafka server reboot, because

1. When producer publishes a message it gets a offset that is
   immutable, and retains across server restart

   2. In Kafka 0.9 and after the committed offset is stored in a topic __committed_offset(You might want to check name of this topic), which is retained across server restart
   3. In Kafka before 0.9 also the committed offset will be stored in Zookeeper and zookeeper retains that offset in log file